# Unable to find web resource from assembly

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I'm trying to load web resources from a linked assembly. Whatever I try, I get the exception:

**Web resource 'MyNameSpace.scripts.jquery-min.js' was not found.**

I'm using the following code to load it:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptResource(this, typeof(MyNameSpace.SomeClass), "MyNameSpace.scripts.jquery-min.js");
```

What am I missing / doing wrong here, causing that exception?

---

My observations so far:

- In the Reflector these resource is visible, and named as `MyNameSpace.scripts.jquery-min.js`
- In the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file of the project, the file is registered as:

  `[assembly: WebResource("scripts/jquery-min.js", "text/javascript")]`
- The file lives in the 'scripts' directory

On a sidenote, I've tried using `Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl()` but this generates an URL without checking if the resource exists. It also seems `WebResource.axd` is not mapped in `Web.config` at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[assembly: WebResource("scripts/jquery-min.js", "text/javascript")]
```

Should be:

```
[assembly: WebResource("MyNameSpace.scripts.jquery-min.js", "text/javascript")]
```